# Interchanging columns in a CSV file

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, pandas

I have a csv file and i need to alter the colum indexes. My current file is

```
A   B   C   D   E   F   G
1   0   0.5 5   1   7   6
2   0   0.6 4   0   7   6
3   0   0.7 3   1   7   6
4   0   0.8 2   0   7   6
```

But i need it like:

```
D   F   G   A   B   C   E
5   7   6   1   0   0.5 1
4   7   6   2   0   0.6 0
3   7   6   3   0   0.7 1
2   7   6   4   0   0.8 0
```

This is just a test case. I have a file with 1000+ columns. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use csv.DictReader csv.DictWriter.

```
import csv
with open('names_in.csv') as csvin, open('names_out.csv', 'w') as csvout:
     reader = csv.DictReader(csvin)
     writer = csv.DictWriter(csvout, fieldnames=["D", "F", "G", "A", "B","C", "E"])
     for row in reader:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Just make sure that fieldnames matches the fields from the input file. You can just copy `reader.fieldnames` and rearange it.

Comment: This works but only for a small file. In a file with thousand columns, its not possible to write down all the column names. Is there a better way?Say i want to bring the last 10 columns to the front in a 1000 columns file. What should be the approach?

Comment: @DigantaBharali You can do that programatically, you copy reader.fieldnames which is a list with all the column names and then arrange it as you wish 
`old_column = reader.fieldnames ;
new_column = old_column[-10:0] + old_column[0:-10]`

Answer (score 1):

You can read your file using `pandas.read_csv` then reorder the columns and rewrite your file with `to_csv`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(your_file)

ncols = 3

cols = df.columns[-ncols:].tolist() + df.columns[:-ncols].tolist()

df[cols].to_csv(your_file)
```

or in one line:

```
(pd.read_csv(your_file)
        [df.columns[-ncols:].tolist() + df.columns[:-ncols].tolist()]
   .to_csv(your_file, index=False)
)
```

Demo:

```
In [12]: ncols = 3

In [13]: cols = df.columns[-ncols:].tolist() + df.columns[:-ncols].tolist()

In [14]: cols
Out[14]: ['E', 'F', 'G', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

In [15]: df
Out[15]:
   A  B    C  D  E  F  G
0  1  0  0.5  5  1  7  6
1  2  0  0.6  4  0  7  6
2  3  0  0.7  3  1  7  6
3  4  0  0.8  2  0  7  6

In [16]: df[cols]
Out[16]:
   E  F  G  A  B    C  D
0  1  7  6  1  0  0.5  5
1  0  7  6  2  0  0.6  4
2  1  7  6  3  0  0.7  3
3  0  7  6  4  0  0.8  2
```

Comment: This works but only for a small file. In a file with thousand columns, its not possible to write down all the column names. Is there a better way?

Comment: Do you have rules which define the way you reindex your columns?

Comment: nope. I just want to insert the last 5 columns , say column no: 997,998,999,1000 to the 1st, 2nd , 3rd and 4th position and shift all the other columns to the right.

Comment: @DigantaBharali, please don't underestimate pandas - it's a very powerful tool. I've added an example to the ysearka's answer of how it can be done dynamically. I think if you would be more specific in your question, ysearka would give you a neat answer.

Comment: @MaxU, I have never underestimated pandas. I am in love with it. Its just that I am new to python and pandas. So i tend to get stuck here and there. Could you lease guide me to any documentation related to this.

Comment: @DigantaBharali, i would start [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html) and then [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/cookbook.html)

Comment: @MaxU, thanks and as for my question I wanted to interchange random columns, e.g, i wanted to bring the 99th column to the 2nd position and the 105th to the first position. Is that possible?

Comment: @DigantaBharali, i would recommend you to open a new question and ask this particular question. You original question was different and it has been answered, so please don't forget to accept the most helpful answer. Please "ping" me from this topic with a link to the new question - i;ll try to answer you there

Comment: @MaxU, yup it did. I found another way also. Check this out `import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('merged_51_final1.csv',dtype='unicode')
a= open('input51.txt','r')
inserted_cols = a.read().split(',')
cols = inserted_cols + [col for col in df if col not in inserted_cols]

df[cols].to_csv('merged_51_final_ordered.csv',index=False)` The input file contains the column names